# getting 403 when i try to curl

Tags: curl, digital-ocean, droplet

I am using DigitalOcean droplet Ubuntu 22.10
And I am gettin 403 when I am using curl on the server but on my local machine its works

I am trying to curl to

> https://www.zara.com/us/

with the right headers
When I am doing this on **my local machine** from terminal its works perfect (with vpn and without)
On the droplet console I am trying to do the same curl and its getting 403
I trying from 3 different droplets

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: curl
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>
 
You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;zara&#46;com&#47;tr&#47;en&#47;basic&#45;heavy&#45;weight&#45;t&#45;shirt&#45;p00526411&#46;html&#63;" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;d04f4317&#46;1668510459&#46;19433a7
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

repeated 'curl'

```
curl 'https://www.zara.com/us/' \
  -H 'authority: www.zara.com' \
  -H 'accept: /' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,he;q=0.8' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'cid: regional' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'referer: https://www.zara.com/tr/en/basic-heavy-weight-t-shirt-p00526411.html?v1=224865182&v2=2113240' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
```

--compressed

Hope you can help :)

Comment: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: curl` -- for starters, you've got a repeated 'curl' somewhere in your command. Can you paste it here? XXX out the API keys/tokens/whatever.

Comment: i edit the post you can see now :) @RogerLipscombe

Comment: there is no way the command you posted will result in ```curl: (6) Could not resolve host: curl``` - the command you THINK you are running is not the command you are actually running. figure out why. i've voted to close this question as ```The question should be updated to include ... the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.```